# How To Install R Packages Via R Link In Windows

Tags: probability-or-statistics, interoperability, rlink

So it looks like I got RLink working on my Windows machine:

```
Needs["RLink`"]
RLinkResourcesInstall[]
RSet["myVar", 10]
10
REvaluate["{
 a <- 1;
 b <- 2;
 c <- 3;
 c(a,b,c)
}"]
{1., 2., 3.}
```

However if I try to install `quantmod` or any package for that matter, this happens:

```
REvaluate["install.packages(\"quantmod\")"]
REvaluate::rerr: Failed to retrieve the value for variable or piece of code install.packages("quantmod").
The following R error was encountered: Error in gzfile(file, mode) : cannot open the connection
```

Any help to fix this and get my packages working via RLink would be greatly appreciated.

Update: Still not working

I downloaded R version 4.1.3 from https://cran.r-project.org/ and set it to my C:\ Program Files directory.

I then ran

```
InstallR["RHomeLocation" -> "C:\\Program Files\\R\\R-4.1.3"]
```

And got this error message

```
InstallR::nxctlib: Warning: no JRI library found for R version 
4.1.3. Will attempt to use the library for version 4.1.2. In case 
of failure, build JRI library from within R console (happens 
automatically when installing rJava Rpackage, see RLink 
documentation for using RLink with external R distributions, for 
more details), and point InstallR[] to it by passing the directory 
containing JRI library (typically R-home- 
directory/library/rJava/jri), as a value for "NativeLibLocation" 
option.
```

I then installed what I believed to be rJave Rpackage from here http://www.rforge.net/rJava/files/

and then ran

```
InstallR["RHomeLocation" -> "C:\\Program Files\\R\\R-4.1.3", 
"NativeLibLocation" -> "C:\\Program Files\\rJava\\jri"]
```

and got this error message

```
InstallR::nonlib: The value of NativeLibLocation option should 
point to an existing directory containing a valid native JRI 
library. No valid native JRI library found at location C:\Program 
Files\rJava\jri
```

I never coded in Java, I barely know what Java is. Can anyone tell me the simplest way to get R fully working in Mathematica so I can run some timeseries forecasts using it.

If I go and try `REvaluate["install.packages(\"quantmod\")"]`

It  will just evaluate indefinitely without ever resolving or posting an error message. It is the same for all packages.

Thanks

Comment: On Mac M1 Max Monterrey 12.1 installing the package results in "REvaluate::crash: Crash in low-level RLink component or in R runtime. Please reinstall RLink via InstallR". `RLinkResourcesInstall[]` does not work for me, and I install RLink with `InstallR["RHomeLocation" -> "/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources", 
 "NativeLibLocation" -> "/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/Library/rJava/JRI"]`. I have the latest version of R for ARM (4.1.3).

Comment: Using `InstallR["RHomeLocation" -> "C:\\Program Files\\R\\R-4.1.1"]` on my Windows 10 machine (*Mathematica* 13.0.1.0) allows `REvaluate["install.packages(\"quantmod\")"]` to work.

Comment: So I take it the key is to have R already installed, install directly and not through Mathematica only.

Comment: That would be my recommendation.

Comment: @JimB is the installation as easy as just downloading it on the internet or do I need to download a separate compiler as well?

Comment: It's pretty straightforward:  https://cran.r-project.org/.

Comment: @JimB see the update to my question.

Comment: @MichaelE2 see the update to my question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135031/discussion-between-daniel-berkowitz-and-jimb).

Comment: This might be helpful:  https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2149434.

Comment: I believe the `rJava` package does not install Java.  It only installs some code to work with Java from within R.  You would need to install the appropriate version of Java:  https://www.java.com/en/download/help/java_win64bit.html.